# reading CSV files and extracting info

Tags: python, csv, average

I am new to Python.

I have managed to learn how to import CSV files and read it.

However I am struggling to understand how to extract specific data.

This is my code to read the data

```
import csv

try:
    with open ("books.csv", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")as file:
        csvFile = csv.reader(file)
    
    for row in csvFile:
        print (row)

except:
    print("file cannot be open")

finally:
  file.close()
```

However, my question is, what code I write to produce a report of the frequency (least frequent first), the list of data is long by the way.

Further, if anyone know what code to use to find most popular (most used item).

Also what code to produce a report of the average length of time a user has borrowed the item, and the proportion of user have returned late, together with average late period.

Comment: We have no idea what your data looks like so hard for us to say. You might want to look at pandas dataframes which can do a lot of this work for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're asking a lot of questions on the same thread. Consider researching a bit more and coming with more specific questions

Comment: We would need to know what fields there are in the CSV and their order.

Comment: there are two CSV files. And I am doing in Jupyter Notebook.
The file books.csv contains a list (a subset) of their books in CSV (comma separated value) format. The CSV files are encoded as UTF-8.
The file bookloans.csv contains data on book loans in CSV format. Each row of the file (there is no header row), holds a book_number, member_number, date_of_loan and date_of_return separated by commas. The date_of_return is recorded as 0 (zero) if the book has not been returned. The date_of_loan is a single integer number representing the date of the loan in Microsoft Excel Epoch Format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage data comming from csv files, wich is essentially a way of storing  2 way tables data, I suggest you use the very popular library called ["pandas"](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html).

It allows you to represent data in such "form factor" and has build in classes to load/save data from/to csv as well as many other popular file formats (excel sheets, hd5, pickle, parquet, feather... to name a few)

[Here is a link](https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read-csv-load-data-from-csv-files/) to a website that explains how to load data from csv files with pandas.

And then, with your panda object, you can perform the `.mean` on a column or a row (use `panda_data.mean(axis=0)` or `panda_data.mean(axis=1)` to perform mean along columns or row respectively)

You also have a lot of usefull methods to find the number of occurences of data in your table, frequency of specific items etc. You can easily find threads that adresses the means to do each specific application you mentioned, using panda objects, on stack overflow, or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

to do what you want, you should follow some steps:

1-read the rows from the sheet in a loop

2-inside this loop, read each row in another loop, then read each item from the row in the loop, then check that it is not space char, then add items to container, list

3-make a loop in each element inside the list and count how much it was repeated inside the list, then add the element and it's repeated times in a dictionary

4-find max value in the dict, then find the key of this value in the dictionary

```
import csv
repeated = {}
list_all = []
try:
    with open ("bb.csv", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")as file:
        csvFile = csv.reader(file)
        for row in csvFile:
            for dat in row:
                for y in dat:
                    if y != " ":
                        list_all.append(y)
    for dat in list_all:
        counter = list_all.count(dat)
        repeated[dat] = counter
    
    max_val = (max(repeated.values()))
    for key,value in repeated.items():
        if value == max_val:
            print("the max item is: {}, and was repeated: {} times".format(key,max_val))
except:
    print("file cannot be open")

finally:
    file.close()
```